# Are airlines responsible for Airport security or Airports concerned or third-parties on terminal-side?

Tags: airport, airlines, security

In Indian Airports, all sort of terminal-side security is done by [CISF](https://www.cisf.gov.in/) . They do all the frisking and baggage screening etc. I am concerned more for the terminal-side security rather than airside where it comes under the airlines domain.

Is it similar in the rest of the world or are airlines responsible? Some notable incidents I recall are the recent Brussels Airport [attack](http://time.com/4707414/belgium-airport-terror-attack/), and the 2015 Sabiha Gökçen Airport [bombing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2015_Sabiha_G%C3%B6k%C3%A7en_Airport_bombing). I would suspect most airports now are under some sort of integrated command and control center modeled on the American system after 9/11 rather than have disparate silo-based security which may have holes that both terrorists and criminals may be able to get through.

I am talking from port of departure, where the procedure is, show tickets, passport at the main gate, go through security check, get boarding pass and board the plane.

Similarly, while de-planing, you go through customs and immigration, security check, baggage inspection etc.

At both places, security check is apparently done. My question is who is responsible, either the Airport Operator or the Government or a multitude of authorities ?

I am trying to be as generic as possible so as to know if there are variances or are most Airports following some set conventions ?
There have been many articles about TSA high-handedness but guess that's to be expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the 9/11 hijackings/attacks, the US passed laws mandating that airport security screening be performed by Federal employees (i.e. the Transportation Security Administration, TSA). [Wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airport_security#United_States)

The Airport is required to provide the facilities to allow the screening process and be designed so that you can't slip past it. The Federal government pays the TSA staff, but Airports can also pay for private security, provided it meets Federal regulations and the TSA approves the plan. This is part of the [Aviation and Transportation Security Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aviation_and_Transportation_Security_Act).

See [this document](https://airportimprovement.com/pdfs/whitepaper_Baldwin_SBA-TSA-Screening-Options_2016-02.pdf) for a lot of information on the subject:

> Section 108 established the Security Screening Opt-Out Program, whereby an airport could petition the TSA for private security screeners. This program was complemented and supported by the Pilot Program, which would develop policies and procedures for private screeners and would also provide real world experience for private screener activity.

As of 2015 it appears that just over 20 airports had privately contracted security

> In its June 2015 report to Congress, the Transportation Security Administration summarized the current status of the Screening Partnership Program as follows: “Since the creation of the program in 2004, 32 airports have applied to the program. Of the 32 airports, 27 airports were approved, 3 airports retracted their application, and 2 airports were denied and have not since reapplied to the program. Currently, 21 airports are participating in the program with contract security screeners in place. Additionally, TSA is in the procurement stage for one new airport. Currently no applications are pending approval.”

Answer (score 1):

In the United States of America passenger and baggage screening is handled by the [Transportation Security Administration (TSA)](https://www.tsa.gov/). It is a government run agency and deals with the pat downs, X-Ray machines and frisks. This will get you through "security" and to the terminal area and ultimately on to the plane.

If you are coming *in* from another country you will need to pass through customs which is managed by its own agents and falls under the jurisdiction of [U.S. Customs and Border Patrol](https://cbp.secure.force.com/applynow/?utm_medium=cpc1&utm_source=google&utm_campaign=a_g12_cpc_national_branded&utm_content=general&utm_term=border%20patrol&gclid=Cj0KCQiAj4biBRC-ARIsAA4WaFhoiDGBE7NYXwxoqmOqntY7NRatNzfNzb_VwhO4lPA69YMCcZGSRCgaAiztEALw_wcB) who are also a federal agency.

At some of the really busy airports here in the US its not uncommon to see local police officers helping out with things like traffic flow and passenger management of those entering and exiting the facility and security in general.

Comment: Another reason to have police at the airport: TSA can't arrest you - the police can. https://www.tsa.gov/blog/2016/07/03/tsa-myth-busters-do-tsa-officers-arrest-passengers

Comment: I can attest that the police are present at FRA/EDDF! After having my bag somehow test positive for explosives (after having already been screened at ORD), I had a friendly chat with several of the local Polizei while the security guy went through everything with a fine tooth comb.